# How do I turn music back on in DDR Hottest Party 2?

Tags: dance-dance-revolution-hp2

I just got *Dance Dance Revolution Hottest Party 2* on Wii. In the options in Training Mode, there's a "Speed" option. I turned it down to 0.7, and a confirmation said, "This will turn song mode off, ok?" or words to that effect. I OK'd it, assuming it meant turning the lyrics off.

However, it's turned off the background music completely — you can select a track and hear it in the menu page, but when you start playing, you just have the moving arrows and the occasional bit of speech, but no music whatsoever.

I put the "Speed" back up to 1.0, but it hasn't re-enabled the game music, and I can't find an option to turn it on in any of the Options pages.

I've also been looking for an option to completely reset the game and make a fresh save, just to get around the problem, but can't figure that out either.

**EDIT** - I worked out how to delete the save in the Wii menu, so have worked around the problem that way but i'd still like to know how to do it in-game.